How likely is for a quadric error matrix to produce negative results in a computer?
A quadric error matrix, cannot, in principle, produce negative numbers.
Quite simply if $N$ is the normal to a plane and $d$ the distance from the origin to that plane. We can define the vector $[N , -d]$ and then our quadric matrix is $[N,-d][N,-d]^T$.
We can see this because $[N,-d]^T [x,1]$ yields the signed distance from point $x$ to the plane. Thus $[x,1]^T [N,-d] \cdot [N,-d]^T [x,1]$ is the squared distance from the point to the plane. And by virtue of being a square, it cannot be negative.
Say, however, that we construct a quadric error matrix in a standard computer. We construct it by creating the vector $[N,-d]$ and then set $Q = [N,-d] [N,-d]^T$.
Assume we are using floating point 32 bit encoding.

Is it possible for the product $x^T Q x$ to yield a negative number due to FP errors? If yes, how/why?

If the above is possible, can I estimate the smallest (largest by magnitude) negative number that can be generated from the quadric metric?


